# Uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope (name Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to debug an error.

```
@scope = ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope.new(
      path:         "",
      shallow_path: "",
      constraints:  {},
      defaults:     {},
      options:      {},
      parent:       nil
    )
```

But I receive an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope
```

Any idea?

I'm using Rails 4.1.6

Comment: The problem is Rails 4.1: Scope.new works only in Rails 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scoping
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html

Comment: How can I create a new scope instance?